# Best JMS implementation for AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, jms, hornetq

I have a Java/Spring application running in the Amazon AWS cloud.
My server instances are using load balancing and runs the same image of a Linus OS, with a Tomcat application server. 
They are also connected to S3 as a shared file system (s3fs), and an RDS database.

My concern is to be sure the state of the different applications is synchronized. Today, the point of synchronization is the database, but when memory caching is needed, out of sync problems appear.

The solution I would like to use is to put in place a messaging system between the applications. For specific reasons, I cannot use Amazon SQS service, then JMS seems to fit my needs. After some reading, HornetQ seems also a very good implementation of it. Once an application state change, it communicates the change to all other applications. Each application is producer and consumer of the same queue.

As we are in a dynamic system where servers and IPs are automatically created and deleted, the automatic discovery of instances seems to be the best solution to use.

But in AWS, broadcast is not possible!

For HornetQ, I saw a kind of work around which is using JGroups additionally. But for me, this is a second framework to investigate and learn. Twice the work. And no more an out-of-the-box solution.

What is your opinion? Does anyone already build a solution for similar needs?
Maybe other out-of-the-box solutions exists?

Thanks in advance for your answer!

Comment: Will a shared cache like memcached work in your situation?

Comment: You are asking for a caching solution, and JMS is just one possibility to synchronize multiple cache instances. So another possibility is to use key/value stores (redis, memcached, ...), but I would look at Inifispan which uses JGroups as well. Your question is interesting, but a little bit too broad for SO.

Comment: @datasage memcached can be a solution for me, if it works in the AWS system (no broadcasting), and handle the automatic creation/destruction of instances. Is memcached (easily) configurable in cluster under these requirements?

Comment: AWS has a managed memcached solution with ElasticCache. You should be able to write scripts to control it. But you can build your own option on top of ec2 instances.

Comment: @datasage My app must be runnable in a "non-cloud" environment as well as in AWS, so depending on ElastiCache is not a good solution for me. But if memcached really works in AWS with its nature (dynamic instances) and restrictions (no broadcast), it is fine for me! Do you have any experience with it in AWS?

Comment: @Asterius I've used it on a small scale, both hosting it directly and with ElasticCache. To use memcached effectively, you are using it as a cluster on its own outside of your normal application instances. You can use it locally, but then you loose some of the benefits of memcached.

Comment: As far as I can read, memcached do not support cache replication. If you have 2 nodes, and 1 is destroyed, you loss the half of the cache. Repcached seems a solution for this, but once again, this is no more an out-of-the-box framework solution

Comment: @Beryllium Infinispan seems to provide the key features I am searching. I will probably test it first, thanks!

Comment: @Asterius You are welcome. The reasons I prefer it are: Embedded in application (= fast), lots of types (local cache, replicated cache, ...), optional persistence, integrated in JBoss admin console. They promise that it will be JSR standards compliant, and they even promise XA transactions on it.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience you could try to use TCPGOSSIP, that is a HornetQ configuration.
See https://docs.jboss.org/jbossclustering/cluster_guide/5.1/html/jgroups.chapt.html